# Unable to update virus definitions in ClamAV/ClamTK

Tags: apt, updates, clamav, clamtk

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 on a Dell desktop computer.I have not been able to update ClamAV/ClamTK virus signatures for some time. The antivirus signatures number is "23296."
When I try `sudo freshclam` I get the following error messages:

```
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

This might be related: I am unable to change the scheduled time for daily updates or a daily scan.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't put my question into a comment, so I'll have to use an answer to ask... give me a couple of minutes to write it.

Answer (score 0):

**Step #1:**

In `terminal`...

```
cd /var/log
ls -al
```

Do you see an entry that looks like this...

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 clamav  clamav 4.0K Jun  4 07:35 clamav/
```

Does yours look different?

```
cd clamav
ls -al
```

Do you see an entry that looks like this...

```
-rw-r-----  1 clamav adm     68K Jun 10 16:49 freshclam.log
```

Does yours look different?

**Step #2:**

Since you indicate that you can't find either of these directory entries, I can only assume that your clamav installation is incomplete. I'd remove it, and then reinstall it, like so...

```
sudo apt-get purge clamav clamtk
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

**Step #3:**

- delete the current schedules in the clamtk scheduler by clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> icons
- in `terminal`...

  `sudo apt-get purge clamav clamtk`

  `cd`

  `rm -r .clamtk`

  `sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk`
- reinstall clamtk_5.24-1_all.deb
- open clamtk, click scheduler, enter times, then click the <kbd>+</kbd> icons

Comment: Actually, I'm not seeing either of those entries. When I enter the first two sets of commands, I do not get a clamav entry. When I type "cd clamav" it says "bash: cd: clamav: No such file or directory."

Comment: Michael... please see Step #2 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: That seems to have updated my virus definitions. However, "sudo freshclam" still provides the same error messages (is it locked because clamtk has a setting to update definitions every day?) and I cannot change the time of the daily scan and update.

Comment: You have to delete the existing time rule and then you can set a new time rule.

Comment: I tried that, but it is not saving the changes in ClamTk. Now, neither is saved. Is there a place to change these settings besides using ClamTK-->Configuration-->Scheduler? Seems like this GUI is not working correctly in Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Go to https://dave-theunsub.github.io/clamtk/ and download the latest GUI interface. Also, have you added many directories in the whitelist? If you have too many, it'll break the scheduler.

Comment: Downloaded the latest GUI as you mentioned. It's still not updating or allowing me to save changes in the scheduler. I have no directories in the whitelist.

Comment: @MichaelE.Lynch  I've added **Step #3** to my answer. Please try it. Test the clamtk scheduler. Report back.

Comment: I think I found the problem. After trying step #3, it initially did not work, because the "+" icon was not activated. I had to hit the "minus" to clear everything, then I could reset the times and hit "+". Now, everything is saved. I think it will work now.
Thank you for your patience and guidance!

Comment: @MichaelE.Lynch please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!